# What information is necessary to successfully integrate a pre-compiled static library into an executable?

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc, abi

Assume that I have C++ static library that I would like to distribute in compiled form, i.e. I ship headers and a `*.a`-file.

What information do I need to provide to the other party to be able to sucessfully use my library, i.e. be able to compile code with it (i.e. compile it into their executable).
The things that I have currently on my mind are:

- Header files
- Compiler, including version, flags (in my case gcc)
- `glibc` version
- C++ standard

Is there anything else?

PS. The target operating systems are Ubuntu 18.04>= and CentOS7.

Comment: What about header files?

Comment: In addition to already mentioned info you may want to tell which OS it is compiled for.

Comment: @Evg My mistake! Headers are of course included. Is in the question now

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Ubuntu (18.04>= and CentOS7). Will add it to the question!

Comment: One way to find out would be to put yourself in the shoes of the consumer, eg. by firing up a bare-bones VM, put a basic dev env on it, then your library and try using it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That is certainly something I will do, but I would still like to be able to write down what exactly is necessary for documentation purposes. And ofc, I also afraid that I will just get something right by accident...

Comment: Possibly also the implementation of the C++ standard library your library is compiled against. For instance, `std::string` is implemented quite differently in libstdc++ and libc++ (both even have different sizes of its binary representation).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that it is the answer you are looking for, but it may be helpful.

Files `*.a` are just archive with `*.o` plus some of info about those objects.
So, in general, it is better to use exact version of compiler and OS, i.e. your client would have all the restrictions as if he tries manually add your object files.

If you would provide an `*.so` file, then it would depends on it's interface.

If `*.so` throws exceptions or its interface includes non simple C-like objects (such as `std::vector` or `std::string` & etc), then only programs of the same runtime can use this library, i.e. you have similar restrictions.

But if you can guarantee that your library will not throw exceptions and doesn't have non Ansi C interface, then only OS info have to be provided.

Aligning to those restrictions (interface consist of just functions and POD data, and throws no exceptions) allows to use different compilers together.

I hope this info is useful for your decision.